# Is it safe to self-reference for MetadataType in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, metadata

I've seen the `[MetadataType(T)]` attribute for MVC, it's all fine and good, but I was wondering if there are any outstanding repercussions of self-referencing the class it is placed on. I've used it, tried it, and it works wonderfully. Too good to be true, in fact. So, what I basically want to know is ...am I doing something dangerous with the following code?

```
[MetadataType(typeof(RegisterViewModel))]
public class RegisterViewModel : IMember {
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [RegularExpression(Text.RegularExpressions.Email, ErrorMessage = Text.ErrorMessages.Email)]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    [Rules("The name you'll login with. You can't use: <em>[ ] | ; , $ \\ < > \"</em>")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter a password.")]
    [StringLength(32, MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [RegularExpression(Text.RegularExpressions.Password, ErrorMessage = Text.ErrorMessages.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Enter your password")]
    [Rules("Passwords must be between 6 and 32 characters, may contain any alphanumeric character and the symbols <em>@ # $ %</em> only.")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must confirm your password.")]
    [StringLength(32, MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Re-enter your password")]
    [RegularExpression(Text.RegularExpressions.Password, ErrorMessage = Text.ErrorMessages.Password)]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no point.

The `[MetadataType]` attribute tells MVC to read attributes from properties on a surrogate class instead of the original properties on the class itself.
It's meant for situations in which you cannot add attributes to the original class (eg, if the class was automatically generated by a designer)

Without this attribute, MVC will read attributes from your class itself.

Comment: Then perhaps you can tell me how to circumvent the use for it in a given scenario. I am trying to load the metadata attributes from the class, but without an instance of it. I have updated my post with the relevant information as to why there was a point.

Comment: Nevermind, you're right. My mistake was that I was re-using the same `FormContext` and the `MetadataType` attribute made that moot. If I don't re-use the same `FormContext` through the different HtmlHelper, then it works fine without the attribute.